# I am trying to apply carousel to multiple images in one carosel.The carousel is not moving. help me

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="CustomStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">

    <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>/*i am not able apply carousel to multiple images in one carousel. give an instruction
```

//i am not able apply carousel to multiple images in one carousel. give an instruction
//i am not able apply carousel to multiple images in one carousel. give an instruction
//i am not able apply carousel to multiple images in one carousel. give an instruction
//i am not able apply carousel to multiple images in one carousel. give an instruction*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code little bit. You need to just replace the existing code with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="CustomStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="item">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="6.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="item">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="8.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <img src="9.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It will work.

Comment: thanks for your response, but this is not working for mutiple images in one carousel

Comment: I've edited the code. You can try this to make it work for multiple images in one carousel.